# How to watch Netflix on Firefox 54 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: netflix

```
Error Code: F7355-1204
```

I'm aware that agent switcher add-on or whatever it's called is an option, but I thought Netflix playing was supposed to be native to Firefox at this point.

I've already enabled DRM content.

About a week ago, I was able to play Netflix on Firefox with no problem and I was running Firefox 47. I had to reinstall my OS this week and now I can't seem to get Netflix to run, even with Firefox updated.

Would like to avoid downloading Chrome if an option. Don't want it running in the background all the time like it likes to do.

**This question is not a duplicate.** The question states that I would like to do so without an agent-switcher add-on if possible. It has also been solved. Not sure why the solution keeps getting deleted.

Comment: Firefox 54 on Ubuntu 16.04 plays Netflix movies with the default user agent -- Did you try the guest account with a totally fresh firefox profile?  User agent requirements do seem to fluctuate, with this being the first time for me the default worked, and other working agents did stop working after awhile.

Comment: Downloading VLC media players appears to download the necessary libraries with it (while also being the best media player). It's a win-win.

Comment: Not sure why the answer got deleted, but I will write it again.

**SOLVED**

The linked question does not answer my question because I was asking how to do so without the solution given.

However, I have found a solution.

The answer is: download vlc media player.

    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc

I guess vlc downloads the necessary libraries, but Netflix now plays with absolutely no problem in Firefox 54.

Worth noting this also worked when I was running Firefox 47, so I assume it works with just about any version